# Jenkins error - Blocked script execution in <URL>. because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, jenkins

I'm aware that if we use a iFrame in HTML we've to sandbox it & add the 'allow-scripts' permission to be true.

But my problem is I don't have a iFrame at all in my pure Angular JS application. When I run it on my local machine it works fine.

The moment I deploy it to my server, Chrome displays this error message along with the below error:

> Refused to load the style 'bootstrap.min.css' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'".
>
> Blocked script execution in
> 'dashboard.html'
> because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts'
> permission is not set.

I'm not invoking the page from a 3rd party site or elsewhere which could possibly inject my source & make it appear in a iframe. I inspected the code & I can confirm there are no iframes at all.

BTW, I use a very old version of Chrome (26) and Firefox (10) [Organisational restrictions]. This happens on IE11 as well (Though no error message displayed) the page doesn't load up.

What could be causing this ? Am I missing anything here ? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a snapshot of what I'm trying to do... Trivial parts trimmed out..

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="dashboard">
   <head>
      <title>Dashboard</title>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/notifications.js"></script>
      <style>
         body { background-color: #F3F3F4; color: #676a6c; font-size: 13px;}
      </style>
      <script>
         var dashboardApp = angular.module('dashboard', ['ui.bootstrap', 'notificationHelper']);
         
         Type = {
            APP : 0, CTL : 1
         }
         
         
         function DashboardCtrl($scope, $location, $timeout, $http, $log, $q) {
            $scope.environments = [ { ... }];
            $scope.columns = [ { ... } ];
         
             $scope.Type = window.Type;
            $scope.applications = [{ ... }];
         
            $scope.selectedEnv = null;
         
            var resetModel = function(applications) {
                applications.forEach(function(app) {
                     var hosts=$scope.findHosts(app, $scope.selectedEnv);
                     if(hosts){
                         hosts.forEach(function(host){
                             $scope.initStatus(app.status,host);
                         });
                     }
                });
            };
         
            var timeoutPromise = null;
         
             $scope.initStatus = function (status,host) {
                 status[host]=[{
                     ...
                 }];
         
             };             
         }
         
      </script>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
      <div class="request-notifications" ng-notifications></div>
      <div>
         <tabset>
            <tab ng-repeat="env in environments" heading="{{env.name}}" select="set(env)" active="env.tab_active">
               <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-class="{'vertical-seperator':$first}">
                  <div class="panel" ng-class="{'first-child':$first}">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3>{{column.column}}</h3>
                     </div>
                     <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="frontends" ng-repeat="layer in column.layers">
                           <h4>{{layer.name}}</h4>
                           <div class="category" ng-repeat="category in layer.categories" ng-class="category.css">
                              <div class="category-heading">
                                 <h4>{{category.name}}</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="category-body group" ng-repeat="group in category.groups">
                                 <div ng-if="!env[group.host]">
                                    <h4>{{group.name}}</h4>
                                    <span class="label label-danger">Not deployed</span>
                                 </div>
                                 <div ng-repeat="host in env[group.host]">
                                    <div class="group-info">
                                       <div class="group-name">{{group.name}}</div>
                                       <div class="group-node"><strong>Node : </strong>{{host}}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                       <thead>
                                          <tr>
                                             ...
                                          </tr>
                                       </thead>
                                       <tbody>
                                          <tr class="testStatusPage" ng-repeat="app in apps | filter: { column: column.column, layer: layer.name, category: category.name, group: group.name } : true">
                                             <!-- Application Home Links -->
                                             <td class="user-link" ng-if="app.type === Type.A || app.type === Type.A1 || app.type === Type.B || app.type === Type.B1 || app.type === Type.C"><a href="{{app.link}}">{{app.text}}</a></td>                                                                                          <td ng-if="app.status[host].statusCode == 0" class="result statusResult"><span class="label label-success">Success</span></td>
                                             <td ng-if="app.status[svr].status != null && app.status[host].status != 0" class="result statusResult"><span class="label label-danger">{{app.status[host].error}}</span></td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </tab>
         </tabset>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

We were using this content HTML in a Jenkins userContent directory. We recently upgraded to the latest Jenkins 1.625 LTS version & it seems they've introduced new Content security policy which adds the below header to the response headers & the browsers simply decline to execute anything like stylesheets / Javascripts.

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

To get over it, we had to simply remove this header by resetting the below property in Jenkins.

```java
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")
```

Those who upgrade to Jenkins 1.625 & use the userContent folder might be affected by this change.

For more information refer https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy

Comment: hi @Venkat after setting this value from firefox is worked now in jenkins, but fro chrome browser ,it still shows this error: because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline'".
 ,anyone know how to prevent this error again?

Comment: @AlterHu - Are you sure the script-src: unsafe-inline comes from Jenkins ? 

As per the documentation, those headers will not be added.

The default rule is set to:

sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';

Comment: it's not from official jenkins site it's from soneone's answer ,like below comments from Nakilon . I had found the root caused is from the chrome browser need to restart and clear the session totally ,then you can get the html page showing in jenkins ,you answer is great .

Comment: Thanks for confirming :) Glad my answer was of help.

Answer (score 46):

You need to follow below steps for solution :

1. Open the Jenkin home page.
2. Go to Manage Jenkins.
3. Now go to Script Console.
4. And in that console paste below statement and click on Run.
   **System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")**
5. After that it will load css and js.

Note : After following the above steps if still it is not loading css and js then clear the browser cache and cookie and refresh the page.

Comment: (After clearing the CSP property,) for me, I need to re-run the test, and then css and scripts would be loaded.

Comment: Does this override (relax) the security implementation completely, right? What should be the command to restore to the previous state?

Comment: @ronnyfm-Restart your Jenkins and it will restore to the previous state.

Comment: Hi Solution by @RonakJain worked for me, thanks. Also Restarting Jenkins restore the previous state. 
Is there a permanent solution of this? so that even after restart, Jenkins do not restore the previous state.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue with [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin).

According to Jenkins new [Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy#ConfiguringContentSecurityPolicy-HTMLPublisherPlugin), you can bypass it by setting:

> hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=script-src 'unsafe-inline';

**UPDATE:**
For some reason on Jenkins 2.x, I had to update arguments again, with an empty CSP value, instead of <strike>script-src 'unsafe-inline</strike>, in order to fully display external HTML pages:

> -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=

On Windows there's a **jenkins.xml** in Jenkins home directory, where you can set global JVM options, such as Jenkins system properties. Simply add it under arguments tag:

`<arguments>
   -Xrs -Xmx256m
   -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle
   "-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= " 
   -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080
 </arguments>`

For most of the Linux distributions, you can modify *JENKINS_ARGS* inside file:

**/etc/default/jenkins** (or jenkins-oc)

For CentOS, modify *JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS* inside file:

**/etc/sysconfig/jenkins** (or jenkins-oc)

See more examples in the Content Security Policy Reference:
http://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: Global MAVEN_OPTS is used to pass arguements to maven & not for Jenkins. So its natural it won't work. Instead you should set this from the Jenkins Scripts console under Manage Jenkins link and just set the property there: 


System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")

Comment: @Venkat - Running  System.setProperty() in Jenkins Scripts console will work for current Jenkins session only, so you'll have to run it again after next Jenkins restart! Whereas setting it in Jenkins Service Java arguments, will make it global.

Comment: yes you're right & indeed that's the way it has to be done.

Comment: hi @Venkat after setting this value from firefox is worked now in jenkins, but for chrome browser ,it still shows this error: because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline'".
 ,anyone know how to prevent this error again?

Comment: @Nakilon - Why did you edit just to add a <strike> tag inside the arguments ? It breaks the jenkins.xml. Please explain or undo.

Comment: @NoamManos, I don't think removing "code" formatting just to striking was a good idea, so I returned it but didn''t notice the strike tag.

Comment: @NoamManos, your formatting is obviously broken. Actually I doubt anyone understands what it means.

Answer (score 9):

For Jenkins hosted on Ubuntu:

1. put to `/etc/default/jenkins`

   ```
   JAVA_ARGS="${JAVA_ARGS} -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"\" "
   ```
2. visit `http://<your jenkins hostname>/safeRestart`

(about this and other options: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties)

UPD: this time when I did this the visiting /safeRestart was not enough. I had to do `sudo service jenkins restart`.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers did not work for me in Ubuntu 16.04 with Jenkins 2.46.2. I had to change JAVA_ARGS in /etc/default/jenkins as

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true  -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"sandbox allow-scripts; style-src 'unsafe-inline' *;script-src 'unsafe-inline' *;\""
```

More info [here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2889)

Comment: I also added "sandbox allow-same-origin" option.

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon Linux at the bottom of `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` change:

```
#JENKINS_ARGS="-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=sandbox"

JENKINS_ARGS="-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"\""
```

Comment: In Amazon Linux 2 this one didn't work, but I have changed in the same file different configuration:

FROM:
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

TO:
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:;\""

Restarted Jenkins and seemed to work.