# How do I fix a Jenkins HTML report "checksum mismatch"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, checksum

I got a brand new Jenkins machine running on Linux Ubuntu. I use  HTML Publisher Plugin to publish my html reports. I also use Jsystem to invoke the test scenario.

- Jenkins 1.643
- Html Publisher Plugin 1.10

At the end of the test when open the **latest** html report from the **project main page** I get this error:

> Checksum mismatch
>
> The checksum of the current wrapper file (0dd0c5ec07dff1d7179f03b5deb290e96ac68f8c) does not match the recorded checksum (090f21ac5f8c4b0eed9e789145a2fe2a6134c900). This indicates a possible security issue, therefore Jenkins will not serve this file. You can access the archived HTML files here.

I have checked existence of file and permissions. If I open the report from the job page then everything works.

**UPDATE**:

When I open the report from the job page I have no CSS and many errors.
Looks like a security issue.

**UPDATE 2**:

CSS and Javascript are back, Jenkins had an update on their [Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy). Added args to the Jenkins startup scripts. First issue is still on. :(

Comment: I have the same problem, asked on the Jenkins issue tracker: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32281

Comment: Good to know I'm not alone in this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in that version of the HTML publisher plug in. The bug happens if you have more than one report in your job, mark the publishing option: 'Keep past HTML reports' and then click on the second report.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32281

Solution in https://jenkins.ci.cloudbees.com/job/plugins/job/htmlpublisher-plugin/61/.

Solution is released as 1.11 of the plug in.

Comment: Thanks I followed the thread my self... I think we can mark this question as answered. Thanks! Special thanks to @Anthony Mastrean for issue tracker

Comment: just verified the SNAPSHOT version, it works fine:
https://jenkins.ci.cloudbees.com/job/plugins/job/htmlpublisher-plugin/61/org.jenkins-ci.plugins$htmlpublisher/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/htmlpublisher/1.11-SNAPSHOT/htmlpublisher-1.11-SNAPSHOT.hpi

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me: [Blocked script execution in <URL>. because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315723/blocked-script-execution-in-url-because-the-documents-frame-is-sandboxed-and/34372607#34372607)

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")

Comment: That't not it. I did had this issue that scripts and css didn't run on the html report but I did sort it out. Look at UPDATE 2