# Where is jenkins.xml in jenkins docker container

Tags: jenkins, docker

We are using jenkins inside docker (version: `FROM jenkins:1.651.1`).
We have problems with the html publisher plugin which isn't executing javascript by default. The same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315723/blocked-script-execution-in-url-because-the-documents-frame-is-sandboxed-and).

We want to change our `jenkins.xml` (just like they said) to change it's configuration. The problem is the fact we can't find it inside our container. Does it has another name inside the docker container or where can we find it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jenkins docker image does not contain a jenkins.xml. This looks to be a windows specific file.

```
$ docker run --rm jenkins find / -name 'jenkins.xml' 2>/dev/null
# returns nothing
```

/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh is run when a jenkins container is started. This contains the line:

```
eval "exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war $JENKINS_OPTS \"\$@\""
```

Therefore try setting the required setting in JENKINS_OPTS:

```
docker run -e JENKINS_OPTS="hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=" jenkins
```

Comment: It does not work "docker run -e JENKINS_OPTS="hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=" jenkins"