# html getting video from source redirecting me to frontpage

Tags: javascript, html, streaming

I've been trying to get a videos source from a website and play it in my own application. When I run, it just end up on the front page of that website.

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html> 
<body> 


<a id="play-video" href="#">Play Video</a><br />

<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="http://vkpass.com/token/bdrxwnlzfjpq/vklhash/Pw7Iy8MztzzwN6xh7nOhf6o80rxCAYIhP8xiQFZ2fGX2.a1aa2ZoFDfJvKt0cycHuydloxHztEjWaRXccGVjbw==?source=v1#" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body> 
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `href="#"` from `<a>` tag.

Comment: Still the same behavior, im new to html stuff if you don't mind could you explain what the href="#" does?

Answer (score 0):

The website has some sort of anti-embedding script that won't allow you to play the video.

But the answer to stop the redirecting would be to use the `sandbox` attribute that HTML5 has for `iframe` objects.

```
<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="http://vkpass.com/token/bdrxwnlzfjpq/vklhash/Pw7Iy8MztzzwN6xh7nOhf6o80rxCAYIhP8xiQFZ2fGX2.a1aa2ZoFDfJvKt0cycHuydloxHztEjWaRXccGVjbw==?source=v1#" sandbox="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

> If specified as an empty string, this attribute enables extra
>   restrictions on the content that can appear in the inline frame. The
>   value of the attribute can either be an empty string (all the
>   restrictions are applied), or a space-separated list of tokens that
>   lift particular restrictions. Valid tokens are:

And one of the options is

*allow-top-navigation*

> [Which] allows the embedded browsing context to navigate (load)
>   content to the top-level browsing context. If this keyword is not
>   used, this operation is not allowed.

By excluding this option in the `sandbox` attribute, it **DOES NOT** allow redirecting/top-level navigation.

Comment: So me playing the video from my page can't be done then i quess? Anyway great answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use video tag instead and remove the anchor tag for play video. Also there is something wrong with the src link of iframe tag, its returning a redirect response instead of video. You can check that by changing the src to the code here and when you download that you will get an HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html> 
<body> 

 <video autoplay="true" width="320" height="240" controls loop="true" preload="auto" src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/habba-cdn/assets/Video/Home-page.mp4"> </video>


</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm tried your code in my local and it stops redirecting when i'm including the property `sandbox=""` as @X33 mentioned and in the console it is showing an error like

`Blocked script execution in 'http://' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.`

This link may help you 
[stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315723/blocked-script-execution-in-url-because-the-documents-frame-is-sandboxed-and)